# Graph REST API -- Reading Email (Java) -- NoPermissionsInAccessToken

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

The objective that I am after is that I would like to obtain an email from Outlook 365 without any human interaction. 
So I am trying to use MS Graph REST API and Java. 
To obtain the access token, I use:

`resource=https://graph.microsoft.com`

```
response = Unirest.post(
                String.format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/%s/oauth2/token", 
                    auth.getProperty("tenant_id")))
              .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
              .field("grant_type", "client_credentials")
              .field("resource", auth.getProperty("resource"))
              .field("client_id", auth.getProperty("app_id"))
              .field("client_secret", auth.getProperty("app_secret"))
              .asString();
```

which returns a string, which is parsed into a JSON, and passed into:

```
jsonNode = Unirest.get(
        String.format("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%s/mailFolders", 
                prop.getProperty("user_email")))
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            .header("Authorization", json.get("token_type") + " " + json.get("access_token"))
            .asString();
```

I am getting the error with the message, "The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood."

I do not have admin access to Azure AD, but I do have access to the `user_mail` inbox, which I can access through `https://outlook.office365.com/mail/inbox`.

I feel like I went off on a tangent, but not sure what else I can do.

Does anyone know what needs to be done to allow me to receive emails thru MS-Graph API? Or a better way of doing this?

Appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: Could you try with /.default at the end of the resource please?

Comment: I tried putting a "/" at the end of `resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/` and still getting the same error.

Comment: /.default this asks for all the declared scopes in app registration

Comment: I added `.default` to resources, and how the error message is "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217". Getting closer :)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to register an application in Azure AD in your tenant and provide the permissions that a user would require access to.

As you are trying to access 
v1.0/users/%s/mailFolders

Looks like you want to use applicatoin permissions (not delegated permissions). So you would need to use Mail.ReadWrite application permissions which would require admin consent too.

You can use this tutorial to get an idea of how to connect Microsoft Graph using JAVA too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java